# Find the total number of cycles in the given matrix

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, graph, adjacency-matrix

Gary has a board of size NxM. Each cell in the board is a coloured dot. There exist only 26 colours denoted by uppercase Latin characters (i.e. A,B,...,Z). Now Gary is getting bored and wants to play a game. The key to this game is to find a cycle that contains dots of the same colour. Formally, we call a sequence of dots d1, d2, ..., dk a cycle if and only if it meets the following condition:
1. These k dots are different: if i ≠ j then di is different from dj.
2. k is at least 4.
3. All dots belong to the same colour.
4. For all 1 ≤ i ≤ k - 1: di and di + 1 are adjacent. Also, dk and d1 should also be adjacent. Cells x and y are called adjacent if they share an edge.

**Input Format**
Line 1:  Two integers N and M, the number of rows and columns of the board

Next N lines:  A string consisting of M characters, expressing colours of dots in each line. Each character is an uppercase Latin letter.

**Output Format** : Return 1 if there is a cycle else return 0

1. I thought that I'll make a 'visited' matrix which will mark 1 for an index if it has already been looked into.
2. Then, I'll traverse for each element and pass it to a new function which will work recursively and return 1 if the cycle exists.
   3.I'll pass the visited matrix, dimensions of original matrix(will be same for visited matrix),int i, int j(i and j are the original indices passes to this function by our original function and does not change during recursive calls), int p, int q(p and q keep on changing to alternate eligible indices), count(if count>=4 and p and q becomes adjacent to i and j) return 1;
3. I'll also create an **iseligible** function to check if the given index is not out of bounds.

*I need help with the approach too. I guess I've overcomplicated this problem. Please help me with it, like in what direction should I think.  I've already spent more than two days on it.*

**Solution.h**

```
int x[4]={0,0,1,-1};
int y[4]={1,-1,0,0};


int iseligible(char board[][MAXN], int n, int m, int i, int j, int** visited){

    if (i<m && j<n && i>=0 && j>=0 && visited[i][j]==0)
        return 1;

    return 0;
}

int solver(char board[][MAXN], int n, int m,int i, int j,int p, int q, int count, int** visited){

    //Base case-if our pq are surrounding of ij and count>=4

    for(int k=0;k<4;k++){

        if(count>=4 && p==i+x[k] && q==j+y[k]){
            return 1;
        }
    }

    for(int k=0;k<4;k++){
        if(iseligible(board, n, m, i+x[k], j+y[k], visited)==1){

            visited[i+x[k]][j+y[k]]==1;

            if(solver(board, n, m, i+x[k], j+y[k], i+x[k], j+y[k], 1, visited)){    
                return 1;
            }

            if(solver(board, n, m, i, j, i+x[k], j+y[k], count+1, visited)==1){
                return 1;   
            }

        }
    }


    return 0;
}


int solve(char board[][MAXN],int n, int m)
{
    int result=0;
    int** visited = new int*[m];

    for(int i=0;i<m;i++){
        visited[i] = new int[n];

        for(int j = 0; i<n; j++){
            visited[i][j] = 0;

        }
    }

    for(int i = 0;i<n;i++){
        for(int j = 0;j<m;j++){
            visited[i][j]=1;
            if(solver(board, n, m, i, j, i, j, 1, visited) == 1){
                return 1;
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;

}
```

**Input handling is done below and it cannot be altered**

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
#define MAXN 51
#include "solution.h"
int main()
{
    int N,M,i;
    char board[MAXN][MAXN];
    cin>>N>>M;
    for(i = 0;i < N; i++){
        cin>>board[i];
    }
    cout<<solve(board,N,M)<<endl;
}
```

Input:
3 4
AAAA
ABCA
AAAA

Expected Output:
1

The output that I am getting:
Runtime error

Comment: I'm a newbie to this graph data structure, and I'm still stuck. I've tried my best but ended up creating a mess and nothing else. Please, help me with it.

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  In addition, use the proper headers, not that `<bits...>` stuff.  Last, use `std::vector<std::vector<int>>`, not `int **` and use `at()` instead of `[ ]` once you do that.  I wouldn't be surprised if you have an out-of-bounds access somewhere.

Comment: *Input handling is done below and it cannot be altered* -- Nonsense -- you're posting on stackOverflow, not in a dictatorship.  If you're going to post code with input, put the input into the program you post.  Don't have `cin` routines if you know the input already.  Just directly set the arrays and variables to that input.  No one is going to want to type in that input over and over again each time they run your program.

Comment: `Runtime error` is likely a result of either an access beyond the matrix, or a stack overflow due to recursion.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie With all due respect, an `<` indirection saves you from retyping the input.

Comment: Too may posters post verbatim what they give to the "online judge" without the simplest of changes.  What I am asking is very simple in terms of putting the input into the program.  No need to encourage this annoying habit.

Comment: `visited[i + x[k]][j + y[k]] == 1;` -- This doesn't look right.  Did your compiler warn you of this line?  Neither does this: `for (int j = 0; i < n; j++)`.  This is where the usage of `vector` would have either gotten it right because you wouldn't have needed to write this faulty initialization loop, or would have thrown an exception if you used `at()`.

Comment: Have you debugged your program? It will most likely show you where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

```
cx=[1,-1,0,0]
cy=[0, 0,1,-1]

def path_helper(matrix,visited,x,y,rows,cols,chars,formx,formy):
    if x>rows or y>cols:
        return 0

    if visited[x][y]==1:
        return 1

    if matrix[x][y]!=chars:
        return 0

    visited[x][y] = 1

    for i in range(0,4):
        dx=x+cx[i]
        dy=y+cy[i]
        if(dx>=0 and dx<=rows and dy>=0 and dy<=cols and matrix[dx][dy]==chars and dx!=formx and dy!=formy):
            if path_helper(matrix,visited,dx,dy,rows,cols,chars,x,y):
                return 1
        else:
            continue
        return 0


def s(graph,rows,cols):
    x,y = (0,0)
    result = 0
    r = max(rows,cols)
    visited = [[0 for i in range(r+1)]for j in range(r+1)]
    for i in range(0,len(graph)):
        for j in range(0,len(graph[0])):
            chars = graph[i][j]
            if visited[i][j]!=1:
                result = path_helper(graph,visited,i,j,rows-1,cols-1,chars,-1,-1)
                if result:
                    break
    return result



x,y = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
graph = []
for i in range(0,x):
    m = []
    l = input()
    for i in l:
        m.append(i)    
    graph.append(m)

print(s(graph,len(graph),len(graph[0])))
```

here the trick is formx and formy parameters which avoid unnecessary Callas.

`

Answer (score 0):

```
int xdir[4] = {1,-1,0,0};
int ydir[4] = {0,0,1,-1};
int visited[MAXN][MAXN];

bool eligible(char board[][MAXN], int n, int m, int i, int j, char curr){
    if(i>=0 && j>=0 && i<n && j<m && board[i][j]==curr)
        return true;
    return false;
}

int path_helper(char board[][MAXN], int n, int m, int i, int j, int fromx, int fromy, char curr){
    if(i>n || j>m)
        return 0;
    if(visited[i][j] == 1)
        return 1;
    if(board[i][j] != curr)
        return 0;

    visited[i][j] = 1;
    for(int k = 0 ; k < 4 ; k++){
        int dx = i + xdir[k];
        int dy = j + ydir[k];
        if(eligible(board,n,m,dx,dy,curr) && (dx!=fromx || dy!=fromy)){
            if(path_helper(board, n, m, dx, dy, i, j, curr) == 1)
                return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int solve(char board[][MAXN],int n, int m)
{
    int ans = 0;
    memset(visited,0,sizeof(visited));
    for(int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++){
        for(int j = 0 ; j < m ; j++){
            if(visited[i][j] != 1){
                char curr = board[i][j];
                ans = path_helper(board, n, m, i, j, -1, -1, curr);
                if(ans==1)
                    return 1;
            }
        }
    }
    return ans;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help.

```
#define li long int
li yes,N,M;
li check[50][50];

void dfs(char board[][MAXN],li i,li j,li i0,li j0){
    check[i][j]=1;
    if(!(i==i0 && j+1==j0) && j+1<M){
        if(board[i][j]==board[i][j+1]){
            if(check[i][j+1]){
                yes=1;
                return;
            }
            dfs(board,i,j+1,i,j);
        }
        if(yes) return;
    }
    if(yes) return;
    if(!(i+1==i0 && j==j0)&& i+1<N){
        if(board[i+1][j]==board[i][j]){
            if(check[i+1][j]){
                yes=1;
                return;
            }
            dfs(board,i+1,j,i,j);
        }
        if(yes) return;
    }
    if(yes) return;
    if(!(i==i0 && j-1==j0)&& j-1>=0){
        if(board[i][j-1]==board[i][j]){
            if(check[i][j-1]){
                yes=1;
                return;
            }
            dfs(board,i,j-1,i,j);
        }
        if(yes) return;
    }
    if(yes) return;
    if(!(i-1==i0 && j==j0)&& i-1>=0){
        if(board[i-1][j]==board[i][j]){
            if(check[i-1][j]){
                yes=1;
                return;
            }
            dfs(board,i-1,j,i,j);
        }
        if(yes) return;
    }
    if (yes) return;
    check[i][j]=2;

}

int solve(char board[][MAXN],int n, int m)
{
    // Write your code here.
    N=n;
    M=m;
    memset(check,0,sizeof(check));
    yes=0;
    for (li i=0;i<n;i++){
        for (li j=0;j<m;j++){
            if(check[i][j]==0) dfs(board,i,j,-1,-1);
            if(yes) break;
        }
        if(yes) break;
    }
    return yes;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But please add textual information regarding **why** you think this would help, or what the solution is you applied. What did you do or add to the code? Why did you do it?

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

bool dfs(vector<vector<char>> &board, bool **visited, int i, int j, char e) {
    //e is the parent character we need to check for the cycle
    //below is the check to avoid out of bound call
    if (i < 0 || i >= board.size() || j < 0 || j >= board[i].size() ||
        board[i][j] != e) {
        return false;
    }
    if (visited[i][j]) {
        return true;
    }
    visited[i][j] = 1;
    // below we remove the current vertex temporarily to call the recursive dfs further
    board[i][j] = '.';
    bool exists =
        dfs(board, visited, i - 1, j, e) || dfs(board, visited, i, j - 1, e) ||
        dfs(board, visited, i, j + 1, e) || dfs(board, visited, i + 1, j, e);
    //attach it back
    board[i][j] = e;
    return exists;
}

bool hasCycle(vector<vector<char>> &board, int n, int m) {
    bool **visited = new bool *[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        visited[i] = new bool[m];
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            visited[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            if (!visited[i][j] and dfs(board, visited, i, j, board[i][j])) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

int main() {
    int n, m;
    cin >> n >> m;

    vector<vector<char>> board(n, vector<char>(m));

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; ++j) {
            cin >> board[i][j];
        }
    }

    cout << (hasCycle(board, n, m) ? "true" : "false");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

/*d=2, left|| d=1, right|| d=4. top|| d=3, bottom
left=1, right=2, top=3, bottom=4
d denotes direction; Using 'd' here for the direction, that shouldn't be considered.
if you have moved to left from right(obviously), then you can't make a move to right (immediately), the direction we can make a move are left, top and bottom.
*/

/*recursive function*/

```
boolean solve(String[]board, int n, int m, int i, int j, int [][]visited, int d, int count){

    if(count >=4 && visited[i][j]==1)
        return true;
    
    visited[i][j]=1;

    //left
    if(j>0){
        if(board[i].charAt(j)==board[i].charAt(j-1) && d!=1){
            if(solve(board, n, m, i, j-1, visited, 2, count +1))
                return true;
        }
    }

    //right
    if(j<m-1){
        if(board[i].charAt(j)==board[i].charAt(j+1) && d!=2){
            if(solve(board, n, m, i, j+1, visited, 1, count +1))
                return true;
        }
    }

    //top
    if(i<n-1){
        if(board[i].charAt(j)==board[i+1].charAt(j) && d!=3){
            if(solve(board, n, m, i+1, j, visited, 4, count +1))
                return true;
        }
    }
 //bottom
    if(i>0){
        if(board[i].charAt(j)==board[i-1].charAt(j) && d!=4){
            if(solve(board, n, m, i-1, j, visited, 3, count +1))
                return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
    
}
```

// solution starts here

```
int solve(String[] board , int n, int m)
{
    
    int d=0;
    int visited[][]=new int [n][m];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
            if(visited[i][j]!=1){
                if(solve(board, n, m, i, j, visited, d, 1))
                    return 1;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: this is unclear as to why it works, please avoid code-only answers and always add some sort of explanation that is not just comments in the code